# Java compiler version and java version is different

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to run a compiled java class and getting errors but when I checked my java environments it points to different version.

Javac –version gives me 1.8.0

And

Java –version gives me 1.6.2

The Java_home and path is pointing to the 1.8 version.

Please help.

Comment: which operating system is it?

Comment: Are you using an IDE like Eclipse or something?

Comment: When set the path set it like set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH% .. It will put your JAVA bin folder in first before others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following :

1) Check your path variable

2) Check JAVA_HOME variable

3)Delete the java,javaw and javaws .exe file from the system32 folder

Answer (score 2):

Java installation under Windows is sometimes a really severe source of pain. The following assumes that you have Windows:

1. Check your path variable
2. Check JAVA_HOME variable
3. Newer versions of Java (1.6 ?, but 1.7 and 1.8) copy some Java executables into the System32 directory of the windows installation. Simply delete this files (or move them somewhere else for easy recovery)
4. running java applications by using .bat files a specific JDK / JRE can be provided.

There may be more sources of your problem. For example with Maven you depend on JAVA_HOME, with Eclipse you have the project settings, ...

Comment: i will check my system32 directory

Comment: Sebastian...it works..I removed java,javaws and javaw .exe files from system32 folder. Thanks alot !!

Comment: @NithinVarghese, if it worked, mark this answer as the correct one. It will increase Sebastian's reputation (he deserves xD) and can help other people with same problem.

Comment: I don't think it is safe to delete `java.exe` files from system32 folder. Internet explorer (maybe other applications too) use this jre to run applets. The correct way is highlighted in my answer.

Comment: I think is safer not use internet explorer ;)

Comment: Hmm, I think that Java should still work in the browser as it should also use the path when calling applets. For jnlp files there is an association with a Java version in the registry which directly points to a Java installation and which is not affected by this removal.
@Nithin Varghese: Please accept my answer if it works.

Comment: The answer provided by Mustafa is also correct. To ensure that future java installations do not break behaviour by re-adding this files you should modify your path placing the Java path before the System32 path. Personally I try to call my Java applications and downloaded jnlp files and so by explicitly providing a JDK as much as possible. I prefer a JDK as some tools (Maven) does not completely workd with a JRE. And for example you can also add Eclipse to the windows taskbar as icon - but only you have added a -vm parameter to the eclipse.ini

Answer (score 1):

`java.exe` while java installation gets copied under `System32` directory. Also we tend to append java path in the end of the `path` variable. This causes running `java` command pointing to the one in `System32` (it takes the first path value that is encountered and ignores rest, in this case java of system32 folder). And when it cannot find `javac` it looks to other values of `path` and finds it towards the end for the java JDK (this is the one you want to use).To overcome this problem give path to your JDK for example `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\bin` as the first entry in the windows `path` variables. Even before your system32 entry. This ensures you point to only one java. My path entry looks something like this:-

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows, you could perhaps check the path environment variable. It might point to an older JRE installation.

Comment: I checked the enviorment variables,thats not the issue .Both the java_home and path is pointing to 1.8 version

Comment: I assume you have a second JRE with version 1.6.2 installed?

Comment: yes i do have 1.6 version also installed but i am not setting any env varibles for 1.6 version

Comment: @NithinVarghese, check Sebastian's answer. You probably have your `java` command under `system32`, which it usually has preference over `%JAVA_HOME%` in your `PATH` enviroment variable. If exisits, delete it.

Comment: @Albert...i deleted java,javaw and javaws .exe files from system32 folder and it work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your Java link is inconsistent. Go to this location (Windows):

`C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` and check where to does `java.exe` point.

In case it is not up-to-date consider fixing it with:

```
mklink /d C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath "C:\Program Files\Java\<your JDK>\bin\"
```

(you may need to remove `javapath` old link before you create a new one)